# Union All Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `pricelist` and `stock`. Those tables have following columns

`Pircelist` Columns `itemno,batchno,mrp,rate`. `Stock` table have `itemo,mrp,batchno,npr,stock`.

Now i want select `itemno,batchno,mrp,rate` from `pricelist` and `avg(npr),sum(stock)` in `stock` table. So i tried this

```
SELECT itemno, 
       salesrate, 
       mrp, 
       batchno, 
       0 AS avgnpr, 
       0 AS stock 
FROM   pricelist 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 0        AS itemno, 
       0        AS salesrate, 
       0        AS mrp, 
       ''       AS batchno, 
       Avg(npr) AS avgnpr, 
       Sum(stock) 
FROM   stock 
GROUP  BY itemno, 
          mrp, 
          batchno
```

Above query retun wrong reslut

But now i am using this:

```
   Dim Rdr As DataTableReader = Nothing

        SELECT itemno, 
               batchno, 
               mrp, 
               rate 
        FROM   pricelist 

     Rdr = GlobalAppSetup.Mthds.ExecuteQry(xQry)

       While Rdr.Read

           Using rdr1 As DataTableReader = GlobalAppSetup.Mthds.ExecuteQry(
           "select avg(npr) as avgnpr,sum(stock) as stock from stock where itemno=" & 
Rdr.Item("itemno") & " and mrp = " & CDbl(Rdr.Item("mrp")) & " and batchno='" & Trim(Rdr.Item("batchno")) & "' group by itemno,mrp,batchno")

                            If rdr1.Read Then

                        txt.Text = Rdr.Item("avgnpr")

                       End If
                        End Using
```

inside the query with above Query

How can i get `itemno,batchno,mrp,rate,avg(npr),sum(stock)` those values in single query

Thanks

Am using 
**Postgresql Version 9.3
Front End Vb.Net 2008**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you're looking for an inner join and not a union all. A union all takes two or more queries and adds them together (I.E, query 1 gets 10 rows and query 2 gets 10 rows, you union all them and get 20 rows).

With a inner join, using the same example you'd only get 10 rows but you can combine the data from each table. Don't forget to use a "group by" so you get a row for each item-- in a group by you have to include all the columns that are in the select statement but not used in group functions like avg or sum.
Try this:

```
select p.itemno, p.batchno, p.mrp, p.rate, 
       avg(s.npr) as npr,sum(s.stock) as total
  from pricelist p
  join stock s on s.itemno to p.itemno
  group by p.itemno, p.batchno, p.mrp, p.rate
```

Comment: @SATSON - I understood the same thing, so maybe the problem might be on the explaining side? If you want to get any further, i suggest you explain more clearly what you _do_ want, as saying "this is wrong" is not goign to encourage anyone to help you very much

Comment: @oerkelens Sorry sir. Ok I will edit the question with full explaination

Comment: @JoeLove - I did not write any version of the question ;)

Comment: @SATSON, I'm reading your latest version of the question and I'm still thinking that you're looking for an inner join. In your example function you are getting the results from the pricelist table and for each row, you're getting the average numbers from the related rows in the stock table. This is the intent of the query I wrote as well. Can you tell me how the query I wrote is not providing the correct results, or what your expected results are vs what the actual results are?

Comment: @JoeLove Wait Now check it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select p.itemno, p.batchno, p.mrp, p.rate, 
       avg(s.npr) as npr,sum(s.stock) as total
  from pricelist p,stock s
 where p.itemno=s.itemno;
```